# Windows - zalenium file upload

Tags: zalenium

I am working in Zalenium, the execution is running. I have a requirement where I have to upload a file from a Windows machine where my dockers are running in a container. Can anyone help? I will explain the scenario in details if I am not clear

Answer (score 2):

You can check "Mounting volumes/folders across containers" under https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/#docker, after that you can upload the file referencing the directory inside the container.

Comment: Hi, I am able to mount the windows path into. Container and also able to see the files.. But file upload to the ui is not working.. I use send keys to send the path and file name.  Currently the path is passed as C:/data (in windows format).  As the execution is triggered from windows machine

Comment: You need to use the path inside the container, not the Windows path as the browser running inside the container does not have access to it, only the local filesystem.